# Return normal result tnt search

Tags: laravel, laravel-scout

I'm sorry if this is a newbie question.

I am using tntseach a s my laravel-scout driver & serach sytem in my app.

It is currently working well but the only problem is the format in which I recieve the results.

If i search for "video" ie http://localhost:8000/search?q=video

i get `["Video post"] as the result.It is correct but I want the result to be just`Video post` ie omitting the brackets and double quotes.

And if i serach  for "posts"

I get:

["My first post","Video post","Posts"]

I want it to be:

```
My first posts
Video post
posts
```

I tried `json_decode()` but that didn't work,probably beacuse it is not true json.

This is my ***SearchController.php***:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\Post;
use TeamTNT\TNTSearch\TNTSearch;

class SearchController extends Controller
{

    /**
    * Display the main dashboard page.
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
    */
    public function search(Request $request){
       $posts = Post::search($request->input('q'))->get('titlek')->pluck('title');

       return view('search.index', compact('posts'));
    }

}
```

This is my search.blade.php:

```php
@extends('layouts.base')
@section('pageTitle', 'Login')

@section('content')

    Your search results are:<br><br>

        {{ $posts }}           

@endsection
```

Comment: Please provide the view template also!

Comment: @Iamzozo Done that

Comment: since the result is an array,  you need to loop through the array and show each.

Comment: @TharakaDilshan Thanks.How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the result is an array, you need to loop through the array and show each

```php
@section('content')

    Your search results are:<br>

    @foreach($posts as $post)
        {{ $post }}<br>
    @endforeach       

@endsection
```

Comment: Thanks.But How do I add a <br> tag after each result?